# Jupyter Notebook OSError: "sh" shell not found

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter Notebook. I'm trying to use pip install to install a package ipywidgets. I can't seem to be able to install it for some reason, the only error I get is "OSError, "sh" shell not found.
I have pip installed in my system. I even installed ipywidgets in the command line.

I've also tried

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install ipywidgets
```

And I get the same error

[image: Jupyter Notebook screenshot]